# Is there a way to change the Routes URL without Impacting the controller its is pointing and paths used in the VIEWS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

Routes.rb

```
scope :module => :abc do
  namespace :old_namespace do
    resources :posts 
  end
end
```

How Can I change the `old_namespace` to `new_namespace`, So that in my URLS I should see the new_namespace. I have too many views where I have used the previous routes with *_path and *_url methods. I dont want to change them for now. Is there any Rails Way to do this.

Things I have Tried,

```
scope :module => :abc do
  namespace :new_namespace,:as => :old_namespace do
    resources :posts
  end
end
```

This Gives me the change in the URLS I need but Also, Gives me and Error
 `uninitialized constant Abc:NewNamespace`

This is expecting me to have constant `Abc:NewNamespace`, ALthough I want this to use the Old Constant, `Abc:OldNamespace`, Something Similiar to :controller option in the resources for the namespace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this,

`namespace :new_namespace,:as => :old_namespace, :module => :old_namespace do`

This is working now.

Answer (score 1):

You Simply do this:

```
scope module: 'abc/OldNamespace' do
  resources :posts, path: 'new_namespace/posts'
end
```

here you are saying,

1. use `abc::OldNamespace`
2. use `new_namespace/posts` as URL path for `posts` resource.

This should work too, let me if this doesn't